# Maven executes only few tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit

I am struggeling on executing all junit tests by maven test.
There are 57 Tests in 10 classes but somehow maven executes only
12 Tests in 6 classes. The ignored classes are in the same folder
as another class, beeing executed.

However, when run my test source folter as JUnit Test it does execute
all tests.

Funny thing: I copied a test, which had been executed, but even the copy
is ignored by maven.

Any help will be appreciated.

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Class names and tests shall have the prefix/suffix "test"

Comment: I knew it got to have an easy solution :D Thanks.
You are welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it is the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) that is launching the unit test and it includes only classes whose name match a condition.

This is documented in the [`includes`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) parameter of this plugin. Quoting:

> When not specified and when the test parameter is not specified, the default includes will be
>
> ```xml
> <includes>
>     <include>**/Test*.java</include>
>     <include>**/*Test.java</include>
>     <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
> </includes>
> ```

Therefore, you need to make sure all of your test classes respect this naming convention. Otherwise, you need to override this default configuration to suit your needs.